# sort table by price column

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

It's the billing list:

```
Service   Price
---------------
S1        13 CHF
S2        Free
S3        Free
S4        40 CHF
```

I want to sort it by price using jQuery or pure JavaScript. (not server-side)

I tried [jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com), but it failed. Because some prices aren't number. (`Free`)

What can I do? Can Tablesorter support it? Or I should use other plugins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own parser. See the documentation at: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

Working example:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'price', 
    is: function(s) { 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        return s.replace(/Free/,0).replace(/ CHF/,""); 
    }, 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            1: { 
                sorter:'price' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8BCHR/

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to go with `textExtraction` and replace `Free` and the currency (as you do). See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4348021/501134

Comment: I didn't realize that existed. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use heavy plugins, you cant to sort it manually:

```
$(function(){
    var table=$('#table');
    var rowsArray=$('tr',table).sort(function(current,next){
        var compareCurrent=$('td.price',current).text().toUpperCase();
        var compareNext=$('td.price',next).text().toUpperCase();
        return (compareCurrent<compareNext)? -1 : (compareCurrent > compareNext) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    $('tr',table).remove();
    $.each(rowsArray,function(index,element){
        $(element).appendTo(table)
    })
})
```

In this example you should add class "price" to cells with prices. Or you can use pseudo-selector ":last-child".

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, but I can't get it worked. Could you provide a working fiddle? (jsFiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry, it was untested and uncompleted. Here is working variant: http://jsfiddle.net/CpPHw/

Answer (score 1):

Here is some custom sort code that will work for you assuming the following:

1. Your table has the id of `items`
2. Each row (`tr`) you want sorted have the class `item`
3. Each price cell (`td`) has the class `price`

Then just include the following jQuery code and call the function when you want to sort: ([**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sSC6y/))

```
var sorted_by_price = false;

function sortByPrice() {
    $('#items').append(
        $('#items').find('tr.item').sort(function (a, b) {
            var td_a = $($(a).find('td.price')[0]);
            var td_b = $($(b).find('td.price')[0]);
            if(sorted_by_price){
                if(td_a.html() == 'Free') return 1;
                return td_b.html().replace(/\D/g, '') - td_a.html().replace(/\D/g, '');
            }else{
                if(td_a.html() == 'Free') return -1;
                return td_a.html().replace(/\D/g, '') - td_b.html().replace(/\D/g, '');
            }
        })
    );
    if(sorted_by_price) sorted_by_price = false;
    else sorted_by_price = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/).
It's very powerful JS plugin.

Comment: I used it before, you're right, it's very powerful, and very heavy. I have just a simple table, and don't want to include an heavy plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have custom, non-numeric values to sort, you will need some sort of custom sort function.  Here's such a custom sort routine for your table:

HTML:

```
<table id="service">
    <tr><td class="sortBy" data-sortType="findNumber">Service</td><td class="sortBy" data-sortType="numeric">Price</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S1</td><td>13 CHF</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S2</td><td>Free</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S3</td><td>Free</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S4</td><td>40 CHF</td></tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
$(".sortBy").click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var tbody = self.closest("tbody");

    // determine which column was clicked on
    var column = self.index();

    // get the sort type for this column
    var sortType = self.data("sortType");
    var sortCells = [];

    // get all rows other than the clicked on row
    //    find the right column in that row and
    //    get the sort key from it
    $(this).closest("tr").siblings().each(function() {
        var item = $(this).find("td").eq(column);
        var val = item.text();
        var matches;
        if (sortType == "numeric") {
            if (val.toLowerCase() == "free") {
                val = 0;
            } else {
                val = parseInt(val, 10);
            }
        } else {
            // find numbers in the cell
            matches = val.match(/\d+/);
            if (matches) {
                val = parseInt(matches[0], 10);
            } else {
                val = 0;
            }
        }
        sortCells.push({cell: item, data: val});
    });
    // sort by the key
    sortCells.sort(function(a, b) {
        return(a.data - b.data);
    });
    // reinsert into the table in sorted order
    for (var i = 0; i < sortCells.length; i++) {
        sortCells[i].cell.parent().appendTo(tbody);
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3w9gQ/